# How can I resign Photo in Django Form

Tags: python, django

I am working a Django project where I want to reduce the image size to be less than 300kb and crop the images to be 1280px 820px. The aim is to make sure every image uploaded is the same irrespective of the initial so any best solution would be appreciated.
Below is what I have tried but nothing works.

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ('.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg')

class PropertyForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    description = forms.CharField(label='Property Description:', max_length=60, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Briefly Describe your Property. E.g. Bedroom & Palour with Private Detached Bathroom'}))
    state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Property.STATE_CHOICES, required=False)
    state_lga = forms.CharField(label = 'Local Govt. Area:', max_length=12, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Local Govt. of Property.'}))
    address = forms.CharField(label = 'Property Address:', max_length=60, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Street Name with Number and Town Name only.'}))
class Meta:
    model = Property
    fields = ('description', 'address', 'country', 'state', 'state_lga', 'property_type', 'bedrooms', 'bathroom_type', 'price', 'is_available', 'image')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['bedrooms'].required = False


def clean_image(self):
    image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')

if image:
    # Check if the image size exceeds 1MB
    if image.size > 1024 * 1024:  # 1MB in bytes
        # Open the image using Pillow
        with Image.open(image) as img:
            # Reduce the image size while preserving the aspect ratio
            max_width = 1920
            max_height = 820
            img.thumbnail((max_width, max_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            # Save the modified image with reduced quality to achieve a smaller file size
            buffer = BytesIO()
            img.save(buffer, format='JPEG', optimize=True, quality=85)
            while buffer.tell() > 1024 * 1024:  # Check if file size exceeds 1MB
                quality -= 5
                if quality < 5:
                    break
                buffer.seek(0)
                buffer.truncate(0)
                img.save(buffer, format='JPEG', optimize=True, quality=quality)

            buffer.seek(0)
            image.file = buffer

    # Check file extension for allowed formats
    allowed_formats = ['gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg']
    ext = image.name.split('.')[-1].lower()
    if ext not in allowed_formats:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Only GIF, JPEG, and JPG images are allowed.")
    
    
else:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Please upload an image before submitting the form.")

return image
```

Comment: "nothing works"? What happens, what doesn't? How have you tried debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use third party library for handling all stuff of image which you want archive then definitely you can use pypi library. It's very straight forward and easy to use

Link [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-imagekit/)

Comment: You should also tell the asker how to use that library for what they want.

Comment: @AKX It's very straight forward documentation and alredy putted code snippet example over there d

Comment: That may be, but see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to use PIL. The Code snippet below makes use of `Models` instead of `forms` but should do the trick

```
#Models.py

from PIL import Image

class Property(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='properties_image/')
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        this_image = Image.open(self.image.path)
        width, height = this_image.size
        TARGET_WIDTH = 1280
        new_height = 820
        this_image = this_image.resize(TARGET_WIDTH,new_height),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        this_image.save(self.image.path,quality=50)
```